# How do I get PackageMaker to create the payload's containing folder with correct permissions

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I'm creating an installer using PackageMaker v3.0.4.

One of the payloads is a library, which I'm installing to the location `/usr/local/lib/`

The permissions of the library itself are set up thus:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    admin  992180  1 Jun  2009 libxxxx.0.dylib
```

This works correctly, so long as the `lib` directory already exists when the installer is run. However, if the `lib` directory doesn't exist when the installer runs, then it is created with the following permissions:

```
drwx------   3 username  wheel  102 30 Jun 10:44 lib
```

And subsequently, the application cannot open the lib when runs the code:

```
void *theDylib = dlopen("/usr/local/lib/libxxxx.0.dylib",RTLD_NOW);
```

How can I get PackageMaker to install the directory with the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>N.B. [Kevin Green's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533185/how-do-i-get-packagemaker-to-create-the-payloads-containing-folder-with-correct/6574870#6574870) looks like a better solution, but this is what I ended up doing.</sub>

If you set the payload to be a single directory containing just the library instead of the library itself, and tick `Include root in package` then the Installer will create the directory with the correct permissions if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory doesn't exist PackageMaker will make it with it's defaults default.

Use a preinstall script to create the lib directory and `chown` on the directory to set the ownership properly.

You can do something like this. This is untested.

```
#!/bin/bash

libpath=/usr/local/lib

if [ ! -d "$libpath" ]; then
    mkdir -m 775 "$libpath"
    chown root:admin "$libpath"
fi
```

Comment: This looks like a better solution that what I ended up doing. I'll change my accepted answer if I get a chance to test it.